# Adding up score in matching game java script

Tags: javascript, css, function, matching

I am quite new to java script so please be patient with me:) So I am making a matching game in java script (matching animal prints with their names) and even if I click on the correct answer, a score is never added, therefore you always lose.

How can I correct this problem?

Here is my code

```js
function randSort (a,b) {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

var questions = [
  {
    text: " What animal is this?", 
    img: "AnimalPrints/1.jpg", 
    answers: ["Cheetah", "Tiger", "Ladybird"], 
    ans: "A"
  },
  {
    text: " What animal is this one?", 
    img: "AnimalPrints/2.jpg", 
    answers: ["Elephant", "Giraffe", "Snake"], 
    ans: "B"
  },
  {
    text: "What animal is this one please?", 
    img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", 
    answers: ["Bumblebee", "Tiger", "Lady bird"], 
    ans: "Bumblebee"
  }
];

var correctCount = 0;
var currentQ = 0;


function select(nr) {
  if (nr == questions[currentQ].ans)
  {
    correctCount++;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You win"
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You lose"
  }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>Score: "+ correctCount;

  // if its the last one
  nextQ();

}   

function showQ() {
  document.getElementById('questionText').innerHTML = questions[currentQ].text;
  document.getElementById('animalPrint').src = questions[currentQ].img;
  newhtml = "";
  for (var i = 0; i< questions[currentQ].answers.length; i++)
  {
    newhtml+= "<button onclick = 'select(" + i + ")'>"+ questions[currentQ].answers[i] + "</button>";
  }
  document.getElementById('alloptions').innerHTML = newhtml;
}


function nextQ(){
  if (currentQ < questions.length-1)
  {   
    currentQ++;
    showQ();
  }
}


window.onload =init;


function init()
{
  correctCount = 0;
  questions.sort(randSort);
  currentQ = 0;
  showQ();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-color:lime;
}

#questionText {width: 350px; background: white;}


#nextbutton {
    background-image: url(Buttons/nextbutton.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    border-radius:10px;
}


#main {
  margin-top:200px;
  margin-left:250px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:600px;

}

#display {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family:aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id = main>
  <div id = "questionText"> Testing</div>
  <div id ="animal">
    <img id = "animalPrint" src = "AnimalPrints/1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id = "alloptions"> </div>

  <button id = "nextbutton" onclick = "nextQ();"></button>
</div>
<div id = "display">    Score:  </div>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the (numeric, 0 based) index of the answer to the function `select` based on the button you clicked. You compare this to the `ans` property, which has the value `'A'` or `'B'` for the first questions.

0, obviously, is not equal to 'A'.

So change `ans` to a value of 0 to N, specifying the index of the right answer, and it works.

Comment: I don't seem to be putting it in the right section of my code, sorry I am still learning.. Can you say exactly where I put this in please?

Comment: Yes. Change `ans: "A"` to `ans: 0`. `ans: "B"` to `ans: 1` and `ans: "Bumbelbee"` to `ans: 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it sorted!